# Relation Card does not exist

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, periscope

The data I'm trying to query and summarize is daily transactional data for cardholders. I'm trying to aggregate first on a daily basis and then on a cumulative basis. I can successfully aggregate by day but when I add the following line:

```
sum(custs_spent_at_least_once) over (order by day rows unbounded preceding) as cum_total
```

I get the error "relation card does not exist"

I have a different query that performs something similar with the same line of code in question.

Here's my code to aggregate by day and on a cumulative basis.

```
with spenders as (  

  select
      [first_trans_date:aggregation] as period, 
      count(member_uuid) as custs_spent_at_least_once
    from
      (
        select distinct member_uuid, min(postdate_and_posttime) as first_trans_date
        from
          (
            (
              select
                card_reference_number, postdate_and_posttime
                , dense_rank() over(partition by card_reference_number order by postdate_and_posttime) as rank
              from
                i2c.posted
              where
                [is_crn_post_launch] and [is_merchant_trans]
              group by card_reference_number, postdate_and_posttime
            )
            as posc
            left join card on card.i2c_ref_id = posc.card_reference_number
          )
      group by member_uuid
      ) 
    group by period 
  order by period desc

)

select 
  period 
  , custs_spent_at_least_once
  , sum(custs_spent_at_least_once) over (order by day rows unbounded preceding) as cum_total
from spenders
order by period desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no column `day`.  You probably intend `period`:

```
select period, custs_spent_at_least_once,
       sum(custs_spent_at_least_once) over (order by period rows unbounded preceding) as running_total
from spenders
order by period desc;
```

Comment: Ahhh. Thank you!!!! This was driving me crazy. Wish the error code was more descriptive.